# ASP.NET Web Service returning Bad Request in Windows Azure

Tags: web-services, azure, bad-request

After a Windows 7 fresh restart, I open the Visual Studio 2010 as administrator, create a new project of Windows Azure Project with ASP.NET Web Role, then at the WebRole1 project I add a WebService1.asmx and press F5 (run).

The Windows Azure services starts OK and the browser open the http:/127.0.0.1:**8080**/WebService1.asmx perfectly. But when I click at Invoke button to test the webservice method I always receive a **Bad Request - Invalid Hostname**, with a http:/127.0.0.1:**8081**/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld.

Comment: When you are running web services in local environment proxy is one big problem, be sure to disable the problem and then try if that works. I was bitten by several time through proxy issues. Also ASMX services are not tested with Azure so if you could use WCF, that is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is ASMX's WSDL file doesn't stand by load balanced environment such as Windows Azure. The test feature relies on WSDL. You will see similar issues if you add a web/service reference. It is recommended to upgrade to WCF. In WCF, you can use useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816894.aspx) to fix the issue. If you need to use ASMX, please try to manually provide a correct WSDL file.